# How to load all items in recyclerView at once?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to inflate all items in `RecyclerView`, My code is not working on devices below `API 24`, here is my code.

This is my `PreCachingLayoutManager` class which extends `LinearLayoutManager`.

```
    public class PreCachingLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
        private static final int DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE = 800;
        private int extraLayoutSpace = -1;
        private Context context;

        public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context, int extraLayoutSpace) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
        }

        public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void setExtraLayoutSpace(int extraLayoutSpace) {
            this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
        }

        @Override
        protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
            if (extraLayoutSpace > 0) {
                return extraLayoutSpace;
            }
            return DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE;
        }
    }
```

This is my activity code

```
 dealsImagesRecyclerView = 
 findViewById(R.id.dealsImagesRecyclerView);
    layoutManager = new
            PreCachingLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    layoutManager.setExtraLayoutSpace(deviceHeight);
    layoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(true);
    dealsImagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 3):

RecycleView is created to optimize the load, to not inflate unnecessary itens.

If you wanna inflate all itens, maybe you should use listview.

Comment: Yeah but recycleView let me the option to set items in horizontal mode, my code is running fine but the problem is with devices with API below 24.

Comment: u can use a simple horizontal scroll view and do add view to it.

Comment: @himanshu saluja
witch kind of view should I add to the scroll view?

Comment: you can use linear layout inside a scroll view and then add each of your views to linear layout programmatically